# Cannot implicitly convert type 'List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'IEnumerable<Models.APPLICANT>'

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Trying To Left Join 2 Tables

```
 public IEnumerable<APPLICANT> GetApplicant()
        {
            IEnumerable<APPLICANT> applicantdata = Cache.Get("applicants") as IEnumerable<APPLICANT>;


        if (applicantdata == null)
        {

            var applicantList = (from a in context.Profiles
                                 join app in context.APPLICANTs
                                     on a.PROFILE_ID equals app.Profile_id into joined
                                 from j in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                 select new
                                            {
                                                Profiles = a,
                                                APPLICANTs= j,


                                    }).Take(1000);


            applicantdata = applicantList.AsQueryable().OrderBy(v => v.APPLICANT_ID).ToList(); 
            if (applicantdata.Any())
            {
                Cache.Set("applicants", applicantdata, 30);
            }
        }
        return applicantdata;

    }
```

But the problem is that im having error at the last Line

```
applicantdata = applicantList.AsQueryable().OrderBy(v => v.APPLICANT_ID).ToList();
```

The error says

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type '`System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>`' to '`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Models.APPLICANT>`'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast)

THIS IS MY APPLICANT CLASS

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public partial class APPLICANT
{
    [DataMember]
    public int APPLICANT_ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string APPLICANT_LastName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string APPLICANT_FirstName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string APPLICANT_MiddleName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string APPLICANT_Address { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string APPLICANT_City { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string APPLICANT_Phone { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string APPLICANT_Email { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<int> Profile_id { get; set; }
```

Comment: Your generic type parameters weren't showing up in either your question title nor your quoted error message, making the question far from clear. I've edited them to make it more visible

Comment: can you please add "APPLICANT" class? your problem is when you you write "select new {" it creates anonymous type and then you try to convert it to "APPLICANT" int this line: applicantdata = applicantList.AsQueryable().OrderBy(v => v.APPLICANT_ID).ToList();. If you provide needed class I can help you I think

Answer (score 4):

It is the type of the collections that is the problem.

```
 IEnumerable<APPLICANT> applicantdata ...
```

is not equal to the type you get from this expression:

```
 var applicantList =
    (from a in context.Profiles
     join app in context.APPLICANTs
        on a.PROFILE_ID equals app.Profile_id into joined
      from j in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
     select new  //<-- this is what dicides the type of the applicationList
             {
                 Profiles = a,
                 APPLICANTs= j,
       }).Take(1000);
```

this mean that you cannot do this:

```
 applicantdata = applicantList...
```

I think you need to do something like this:

```
applicantdata = applicantList
                   .SelectMany(c => c.APPLICANTs) //this line added
                   .AsQueryable().OrderBy(v => v.APPLICANT_ID).ToList();
```

**UPDATE**

If you are using my "solution" with `SelectMany`, you should be asking yourself - "Am I extracting the right data when I create `applicationList`..?"

perhaps this is better..:

```
var applicantList =
    (from a in context.Profiles
     join app in context.APPLICANTs
        on a.PROFILE_ID equals app.Profile_id into joined
      from j in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
     select j //<--  this is APPLICANTs type
       }).Take(1000);
```

Comment: After Adding that line . . New Error pops out 

The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Queryable.SelectMany<TSource,TResult>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TSource,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: Its hard to say what the problem is with out the metadata on `APPLICANTs`. Can you post it

Comment: @EnriqueGil The class looks ok. What is the problem. If you still go with the `SelectMany` solution, try adding a Type praram: `SelectMany<APPLICANTs>(c => c.APPLICANTs)..`

Comment: After tryng your code 
this error Appear 

Applicant.Models.APPLICANT' does not contain a definition for 'APPLICANTs' and no extension method 'APPLICANTs' accepting a first argument of type 'Applicant.Models.APPLICANT' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Error on this line maybe because APPLICANTs is my DBSet . . What should i use now?

applicantdata = applicantList
                   .SelectMany(c => c.APPLICANTs) //this line added
                   .AsQueryable().OrderBy(v => v.APPLICANT_ID).ToList();

Comment: @EnriqueGil did you implement both the `SelectMany` solution and the one where you alter the linq that creates `applicationList`? :) I suggest remove the `SelectMany` (interly) and then it should work

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is not converting from a list to an IEnumerable.  Instead, the problem is that you cannot convert an LIST of annonoymous object to an IEnumerable of APPLICANT.

You should modify your select statement so you're selecting an APPLICANT.