# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

Now that im trying the Right Join An Exception Popped up.

This is my Controller

```
   public IEnumerable<APPLICANT> GetApplicant()
    {
        IEnumerable<APPLICANT> applicantdata = Cache.Get("applicants") as IEnumerable<APPLICANT>;
        IEnumerable<Profile> profiledata = Cache.Get("profiles") as IEnumerable<Profile>;


        if (applicantdata == null)
        {

            var applicantList = (from a in context.Profiles 
                                 join app in context.APPLICANTs
                                 on a.PROFILE_ID equals app.Profile_id into joined
                                 from j in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                 select new
                                            {
                                               APPLICANT = j, 
                                               Profile = a,
                                            }).Take(1000).AsEnumerable();

                   applicantdata = applicantList.AsEnumerable().ToList();


            if (applicantdata.Any())
            {
                Cache.Set("applicants", applicantdata, 30);
            }
        }
        return applicantdata;

    }
```

This is the error on

```
 applicantdata = applicantList.AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Applicant.Models.APPLICANT>'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: How you define `APPLICANT`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot implicitly convert type 'List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'IEnumerable<Models.APPLICANT>'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16602765/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-listanonymoustype1-to-ienumerablemodels-ap)

Comment: If you are using `IEnumerable<Applicant>` as return type, then why are you creating an Anonymous type in the LINQ?? 
You need to use `select new Applicant{ }`

Answer (score 2):

`applicantdata` is `IEnumerable<APPLICANT>`, in your select statement you are selecting [anonymous type object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx) using `new` keyword, that is why you can't convert it to `IEnumerable<APPLICANT>`.

You have to create a temporay class with your properties as in select statement and return `IEnumerable` of that class.

Like:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public APPLICANT applicant {get;set;}
  public Profile porfile {get;set;}
}
```

Then modify your function to return `IEnumerable<MyClass>` like

```
public IEnumerable<MyClass> GetApplicant()
{
    IEnumerable<MyClass> applicantdata = Cache.Get("applicants") as IEnumerable<MyClass>;
    IEnumerable<Profile> profiledata = Cache.Get("profiles") as IEnumerable<Profile>;

    IEnumerable<MyClass> applicantList;
    if (applicantdata == null)
    {

        applicantList = (from a in context.Profiles 
                             join app in context.APPLICANTs
                             on a.PROFILE_ID equals app.Profile_id into joined
                             from j in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             select new MyClass //Change here
                                        {
                                           APPLICANT = j, 
                                           Profile = a,
                                        }).Take(1000);

               applicantdata = applicantList.AsEnumerable();



        if (applicantdata != null && applicantdata.Any())
        {
            Cache.Set("applicants", applicantdata, 30);
        }
    }
    return applicantdata;

}
```

You can't project to `APPLICANT`, since that appears to be a class generated through entity framework.

Comment: You need to change applicantdata to be of type MyClass and put the assignment back in.  The whole point of the code is to avoid the query if it is already in the cache!

Comment: i think sir this is not working because applicantdata is my container

Comment: @BobVale, yes. Thanks for pointing that out, I was more focusing on the error, then the general method, but thanks again

Comment: @EnriqueGil, I am not sure about your design, but you can put `IEnumerable<MyClass>` in your cache, but I guess you got the reason why you were getting the error, You are selecting anonymous object and trying to return a different type from what you have in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining applicant data to be a `IEnumerable<APPLICANT>` however the return type of applicant list is an `IEnumerable<{Anonymous Type}>`

You need some function to convert from your anonymous value to an Applicant if you want to use it in this fashion.

Answer (score 0):

You Can set your return type

```
IQueryable
```

Then return

```
applicantList.AsEnumerable().ToList().AsIQueryable();
```

Like

```
public IEnumerable<APPLICANT> GetApplicant()
{
  applicantdata = applicantList.AsEnumerable().ToList().AsQueryable();

}
```

Will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not an efficient way to implement because when you call .ToList it execute the query and grab the data to the memory and after that you again convert to .AsQueryable().  Imagine if you have thousand records and how much it cost. 
If I am wrong please correct me. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning IEnumerable rather return IEnumerable and then when you do the query call .ToLost() on it.

```
public IEnumerable GetApplicant()
    {
        IEnumerable<APPLICANT> applicantdata = Cache.Get("applicants") as IEnumerable<APPLICANT>;
        IEnumerable<Profile> profiledata = Cache.Get("profiles") as IEnumerable<Profile>;


        if (applicantdata == null)
        {

            var applicantList = (from a in context.Profiles 
                                 join app in context.APPLICANTs
                                 on a.PROFILE_ID equals app.Profile_id into joined
                                 from j in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                 select new
                                            {
                                               APPLICANT = j, 
                                               Profile = a,
                                            }).Take(1000); //AsEnumerable();

                   applicantdata = applicantList.ToList(); //applicantList.AsEnumerable();


            if (applicantdata.Any())
            {
                Cache.Set("applicants", applicantdata, 30);
            }
        }
        return applicantList.ToList(); //applicantdata;

    }
```