# How to use List<dynamic>

Tags: c#, list, dynamic

I need to get the list of billers from my database.
here is my code:

```
public static List<dynamic> GetBillers()
{
    DataLayer.DLContext context = new DataLayer.DLContext();

    var Billers = (from b in context.Biller
                   where b.IsActive == true && b.IsDeleted == false
                   select new
                   {
                       ID = b.ID,
                       DisplayName = b.DisplayName
                   }).ToList();

    return Billers;
}
```

I am getting this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>` to `System.Collections.Generic.List<dynamic>`

Please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16645626/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-system-collections-generic-listanonymoustype1 will help you

Comment: Why not just create a Dto to store the objects? Then you aren't relying on `dynamic`..

Answer (score 6):

```
(from b in context.Biller
 where b.IsActive == true && b.IsDeleted == false
 select (dynamic) new {
     ID = b.ID,
     DisplayName = b.DisplayName
 }).ToList();
```

should do the job. Personally, though, I'm not sure it is a particularly helpful move - I would suggest returning a known class / interface instead. `dynamic` has various uses, but this isn't a good one.

Answer (score 1):

Cast to dynamic:

```
var Billers = (from b in context.Biller
               where b.IsActive == true && b.IsDeleted == false
               select new
               {
                   ID = b.ID,
                   DisplayName = b.DisplayName
               }).ToList<dynamic>();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not assign a `List<T>` to a `List<dynamic>` object. You need to add each object one by one;

```
        var temp = new List<dynamic>();
        foreach (object obj in Billers)
        {
            temp.Add(obj);
        }
```

Comment: It can also be done in the existing query; also, here you are significantly changing the semantic: the original query only made the `ID` and `DisplayName` available - presumably quite deliberately. This makes the original object available. That can be good or bad, but : it isn't the same as the result of the code in the question.